# Taxonomy control in SharePoint hosted app

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I am creating an SharePoint hosted app. In that I have to use Managed MataData from my list. In this I am getting the Metadata from my list column to my Taxonomy control.

I have find some post but I am not able to get the all the meta data. Code I am using is as below.

```
function execOperation() {
    try {
        context = new SP.ClientContext(hostweburl);
        var factory =
            new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(
                appweburl
            );
        context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
        appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);
        web = appContextSite.get_web();
        context.load(web);
        //My List with Taxonomy column
        taxonomyList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Test");

        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}

function onSuccess() {
    try {
        debugger;
        //Getting the taxonomy filed from the list
        taxonomyControl = taxonomyList.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Name");
        context.load(taxonomyControl);
        taxField = context.castTo(taxonomyControl, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
        context.load(taxField);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessTaxonomyValues, onFail);

    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}

//This code is suppose to fill the taxonomy filed. But it is not working.
function onSuccessTaxonomyValues() {
    debugger;
    var webTaggingCtl = $get("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01editableRegion");//On page taxonomy control.
    var taxCtlObj = new SP.Taxonomy.ControlObject(webTaggingCtl);
    taxCtlObj.enableControl(true);
    taxCtlObj.setRawText(taxField);
    taxCtlObj.retrieveTerms();
}
```

My actual question is How can I fill `TaxonomyWebTaggingControl` control, which I placed on my page, with the above code?
Can any one help me to solve this?
Thank you in advance...!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling your callback functions, rather than passing a reference to them into `executeQueryAsync`. Your callbacks are probably executing before the data has been retrieved.

Have you tried this

```
context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessTaxonomyValues, onFail)
```

instead of this

```
context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessTaxonomyValues(), onFail());
```

and this

```
context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessTaxonomyValues, onFail);
```

instead of this

```
context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessTaxonomyValues(), onFail());
```

Comment: The success methods here are getting executed. Nothing it take if I pass braces there. My Actual question is how can I fill `TaxonomyWebTaggingControl` with this code.

Comment: And if I remove braces from the method It gives me error. I have asked Question please check If you can solve. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88653/invalid-field-or-parameter-requestinfo-url-in-sharepoint-hosted-app

Comment: What is the error when you remove the parentheses?

Comment: The Error has been solved. But this is still remains that how to use Taxonomy control.